# datagridview Mouse Down clear previous selection row

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I set `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`mode, set`MultiSelect=true`, I want when I select one row1, triggle another row2 selected too, it works fine by implement`CellClick`event, but when I press mouse click down(hold) at any row, row2 appears unseleceted, even I work with `CellMouseDown` event, can I press mouse click down(hold) a row not affect previous selected rows? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
private void _dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        GridColumns currRow = (GridColumns)_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        string currRowUID = currRow.GetRowUID();
        if (e.RowIndex + 1 < _dataGridView.RowCount)
        {
            GridColumns nextRow = (GridColumns)_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].DataBoundItem;
            string nextRowUID = nextRow.GetRowUID();
            if (currRowUID == nextRowUID)
                if (!_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Selected)
                {
                    _dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Selected = true;
                    _dataGridView.Refresh();
                }
        }
        if (e.RowIndex - 1 > -1)
        {
            GridColumns nextRow = (GridColumns)_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex - 1].DataBoundItem;
            string nextRowUID = nextRow.GetRowUID();
            if (currRowUID == nextRowUID)
                if (!_dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex - 1].Selected)
                {
                    _dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex - 1].Selected = true;
                    _dataGridView.Refresh();
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: To select multiple rows you need to have the `ctrl` key pressed also.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I need select one row,  selected another row at the same time, not press ctrl key

Comment: [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961351/2268680) solve my question, add a before and after event of cellmouseclick